# JS/CSS aggregation not creating css folder

Tags: 8, css-js-aggregation

I am creating a Drupal 8 website with a custom theme. 
When css and js aggregation checkboxes are checked, js directory is created in sites/default/files/, however css folder does not get created.

Also all js and css is not working.

When I ran this command in terminal **ls -l sites/default/** I get the following line for files folder

**drwxrwxrwx  7 admin  staff    224 May 10 10:30 files**

Would there be any reason the site does not create css folder in sites/default/files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this issue is due to incorrect permission. Can you check the permission on the folders. It will also be helpful if you print the related error/warning/notice logs with the question.

Thanks

Comment: There is no specific error or logs for this issue. I edited the question adding permission code for sites/default/files directory

Comment: What server are you using? Usually the server is the owner of the files/ folder (www-data). You can check for relevant notices on the Status report page and Recent log messages (Under Reports).